# No signal to monitors after forced shutdown

Tags: boot, display, graphics-card, motherboard, hardware-failure

I forced a shutdown of my computer when it was locked and not doing anything (important). When I came back some hours later and pressed the power button. It turned on (lights, fans spinning) but there was no signal to screens. This has happened before and it usually fixes itself if I restart the computer a couple of times. But this time it is not solved even after 50+ restarts. The screens work if I connect my laptop to them, so there is no problem with the screens or their cables.

I have now also removed graphics card, ram sticks, PSU (for 1 hour) checked every cable, cleared CMOS by removing battery (2 times) and placing metal against JBAT1 pins, tried different cable for graphics card, different RAM-configuration and nothing seems to solve it.

When booting the computer, I can see on the motherboard a red light next to a VGA label. I am assuming this indicates some problem with the graphics card. However, I recently ran several benchmarks on all my components and it said it performed well and found no problems. The pins on the graphics card connecting to motherboard look brand new and the fans of the graphics card are spinning.

The computer has these parts:

```
Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 2600X Six-Core Processor 3.60 GHz
Graphics card: Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060 6GB
Power supply: Corsair RM750X 750W v2
SSD: Crucial MX500 500GB 2.5"
RAM: Corsair 32GB (x8GB) DDR4 3000MHz CL15 Vengeance LPX
Motherboard: B450 GAMING PRO CARBON AC (MS-7B85)
```

and two weeks ago I updated BIOS to stable 2023 version to fix a RAM issue, it has worked since that time. What could be the problem? How would I troubleshoot this? I can't even get into BIOS settings.

Below is the red VGA light on the motherboard. I don't know if that is new or not.
[image]

Comment: Hm, if you google the name of the motherboard + vga red light you get a lot of people with similar problems https://www.google.com/search?q=B450+GAMING+PRO+CARBON+AC+vga+red+light

Comment: @Gantendo Hm yes, but most of them seem to be after building PC or upgrading something. Weird for it to work 110% one moment and one shutdown later it wont boot at all with no changes to hardware.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I can't get into BIOS because my screen(s) get no signal at all. What do you mean Run live ubuntu from USB? If I can't get a display, what am I supposed to do with that?

Comment: and if you connect a monitor directly to the motherboard, not to the GPU?

Comment: @Gantendo Correct me if I am wrong, but that won't work unless the CPU has integrated graphics. My Ryzen 2600x does not have integrated graphics, and I got no signal when I tried that either

Comment: @jgklsdjfgkldsfaSDF Ah yeah. That makes troubleshooting harder.

Comment: @Gantendo Yep, I really do not know what to do here. How likely is it that a motherboard fails randomly after 4 years of normal use with no prior problems? I guess the next step would be to buy a new motherboard but that would really suck

Comment: Could it help to downgrade bios version to previous one? Even though it worked flawlessly with new version for past weeks?