# Can I replace Corsair RM750X 750W v2 with Corsair CMPSU-450VX for testing purposes?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure

I recently encountered a problem where I suddenly got no signal to display after my computer has worked for 4 years [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1804222/no-signal-to-monitors-after-forced-shutdown). I still have no idea how to solve it but I got access to an old PSU I want to try to replace my current one with to rule my PSU out as the culprit.

However, I can't seem to match the cables. In my current setup with my current PSU ( Corsair RM750X 750W v2 ) I have one cable with two "subcables"(?) where one has 2x3 pins and the other has 2x1 pins, connecting to the graphics card. Then I have a CPU cable with 2x4 pins, and a cable with 2x12 pins connecting straight to the motherboard. On the replacement PSU (Corsair CMPSU-450VX) however, ignoring all the peripheral harddrive cables and such, I only have one 2x3 cable labeled PCI-e and a two 2x2 cables connected in one cable. There is a 2x12 pin cable, the same as my current PSU, connecting to the motherboard though.

Current cables and sockets:

CPU CABLE
[image: CPU cable]

GPU SOCKET
[image: GPU socket]

CPU SOCKET
[image: CPU socket]

Relevant cables on new PSU:

Not labeled, CPU?
[image: Not labeled cable, I am assuming CPU]

PCI-e cable, into graphics card?
[image: PCI-e cable, does this go into graphics card?]

Question: Will it work to replace Corsair RM750X 750W v2 with Corsair CMPSU-450VX for short term testing or is there a risk of ruining my hardware? If it works, am I correct in assuming that the 2x3 PCI-e cable goes into the graphics card even though my old cable has 2x3 and 2x1? Does the cable with two 2x2 subcables go into my CPU slot even though my old cable was 2x4? If so, in what slots?

Comment: Don’t use cables from on PSU with the other PSU they are not compatible but the two PSUs by themselves should be compatible. I would be more worried that the new PSU is powerful enough to support all your hardware. Not actually willing to say if it is or isn’t compatible just wanted to make sure you didn’t try switching the cables around.

Comment: @Ramhound What I simply will do is remove the cables from CPU, GPU, MOTHERBOARD connected to my current PSU, and connect the cables from the replacement PSU instead, outside the case, and power my computer with replacement PSU for 10 min just to see if I get a display signal. I too realize it might not be powerful enough, but if the worst case is that nothing happens and no explosions im willing to take the risk. Just wondering how I should connect the cables.